# mention extensions when split (linux)

Tags: linux, split

I have a pretty simple question:

```
exec('split -d -l 10 _.txt part');
```

This splits my _.txt file into chunks part00,part01 etc.
Can i set file extension for these chunks somehow?
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by using the `--filter` option as documented in `info coreutils 'split invocation'`:

```
split -d -l 10 _.txt part --filter='cat > $FILE.txt'
```

This will create *part00.txt*, *part01.txt* and so on. Also seems to work for binary files (with `-b` instead of `-l`).

Comment: just like this example (split -b200G --filter='xz > $FILE.xz' - big-) I am using exec("split -d -l 10 _.txt part --filter='txt > $FILE.txt'");    and no chunk file is created

Comment: when i use exec("split -d -l 10 _.txt part --filter=txt > pt.txt"); the pt.txt is created but it is empty. sorry, cannot get how this command works

Comment: *txt* is not a correct filter, `--filter` requires a command like `cat` or `xz`. Why don't you try the command I posted? You may have to escape the inner quotes if you are already using the same quotes around the whole command or use different quotes outside if possible.

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob Which system are you using? This is `split` from the GNU core utilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
# touch xaa xab xac; for f in xa{a..c};do echo mv -- "$f" "$f.txt";done
```